# как лучше сделать импорт в БД WordPress и делать сверку на дубликаты?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных

Как лучше сделать импорт из csv файла в кастомную таблицу БД WordPress?
я предполагаю 2 способа

1. Перед записью каждой строки в БД делать проверку на существование (отправлять запрос) и если ее нет - добавлять
2. Получить все записи из таблицы БД в виде массива и перебирать каждую строку файла сверяя ее с массивом таблицы из БД - если срока уникальна = добавляем в БД (или после полной сверки все уникальные строки сразу добавить в БД).

   Подскажите пожалуйста  как лучше это сделать с точки зрения нагрузки и рациональности.
   Или если у вас есть более правильное решение данной задачи - напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: С точки зрения разумность сперва определяются цели и только потом ищутся пути решения.  [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/504949)

Comment: цель: запись в бд без дубликатов. Решение выбрать - более рациональный способ или предложить свой (по вашему мнению)

Comment: Каких дубликатов? Дубликатов чего? Собственно, лучше задать отдельный вопрос, на этот раз правильный. Описывая проблему, а не придумавшая пути её решения.

Comment: дубликаты это одинаковые строки . В БД не должно создаваться одинаковых строк. Для этого проводится сверка пред записью на наличие уже такой строки в БД.

Comment: Никаких одинаковых строк быть не должно. В ВП сквозной автоинкремент. И да импортируют не "строки", а "данные". Нужно вникнуть в этот постулат.

Comment: Оба способа никуда не годятся. Хотя и второй лучше первого. Такие вещи правильно делать через MySQL https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361368/6817117.